# How can I implement the same code without using didSet?

Tags: swift

I have implemented this code for setting images of the button to implement checkbox using `didSet` function.

But now I don't want to use `didSet` function.

Please suggest me other way to implement the same code without using `didSet`.

```
//changing image using didSet              

didSet 
{
  if (self.isChecked == true)
  {
      self.setImage(checked, forState: .Normal)
  }
  else
  {
      self.setImage(unChecked, forState: .Normal)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use `didSet`? It seems like the right place to do it.

Comment: func storeValue (sender : UIButton)
    {
        if(sender.currentTitle == "pro1")
        {
            response["Apple"] = valueCheckbox
            
        }else if(sender.currentTitle == "pro2")
        {

            response["Samsung"] = valueCheckbox

        }else if(sender.currentTitle == "pro3")
        {
            response["Blackberry"] = valueCheckbox
        }
        else if(sender.currentTitle == "pro4")
        {    response["Motorola"] = valueCheckbox
        }

Comment: This function we are calling inside didSet and when i am using core data,without pressing the button the values are saved to core data which i don't want. i want that values to be stored only when i will press the checkbox. Why  i am calling this function inside didSet is because i am getting the state of button only in didSet.

Comment: I suggest you update your question with this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UISwitch with custom images set in the storyboard, then you just read the value